# Switch enum on attributes in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having this enum:

```
enum ContentError {
  e410('Exception: 410'),
  e411('Excetion: 411'),
  e412('Exception: 412'),
  e413('Exception: 413');

  const ContentError(this.name);

  final String name;
}
```

Now I get some String and I want to do a switch case on the names of the Enum.

```
switch (myString) {
  case ContentError.e410.name:
    // do something
  ...
}
```

but this does not work as it says `The property 'name' can't be accessed on the type 'ContentError' in a constant expression.`

How can I do a switch case on the Enum attriute `name`?

**EDIT**:
See this [dart.pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=44e53a1907cc35a612c26be2c67b65b4) as an MRE

Comment: @jarinox I don't really understand why this is a constant expression and how I would need to change it.

Comment: @jarinox hm no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you won't be getting exhaustiveness from switching over a string anyway, you can just use `singleWhere` to get the enum value from the string and use try-catch:

```dart
try {
  final contentError = ContentError.values.singleWhere((e) => e.name == myString);

  switch (contentError) {
    case ContentError.e410:
    // Do something
  }
} on StateError {
  // The 'default' case
}
```

That code will catch `StateError` coming from any of the code in the switch cases though, so a better solution could be:

```dart
ContentError? contentError;
try {
  contentError = ContentError.values.singleWhere((e) => e.name == myString);
} on StateError {
  // The 'default' case
}

if (contentError != null) {
  switch (contentError) {
    case ContentError.e410:
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not work as I get `The expression of a constant pattern must be a valid constant.`. Because `contentError` is not a const.

Comment: Then surely your question is missing some details. Please update your question to include your _actual_ problem.

Comment: Actually that is all I am doing

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. In fact, all of these answers here including my answer can run correctly over the circumstances that you explained in your question. You _must_ provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that everyone can run to get the _exact_ error that you're getting. Currently, your short code snippets do not help at all at reproducing the problem.

Comment: Here is the dartpad =>  https://dartpad.dev/?id=44e53a1907cc35a612c26be2c67b65b4

Comment: So the problem now is just a typo. You typed `case backendError.e410` (small 'b') instead of `case BackendError.e410` (capital 'B'). `backendError` refers to the local final variable that you defined in that scope, while `BackendError` refers to the enum. If you fix it, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
enum ContentError {
  e410,
  e411,
  e412,
  e413,
}

extension ContentErrorExtension on ContentError {
  String get name {
    switch (this) {
      case ContentError.e410:
        return 'Exception: 410';
      case ContentError.e411:
        return 'Exception: 411';
      case ContentError.e412:
        return 'Exception: 412';
      case ContentError.e413:
        return 'Exception: 413';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  String myString = 'Exception: 410';

  switch (myString) {
    case ContentError.e410.name:
      print('Handling Exception 410');
      break;
    case ContentError.e411.name:
      print('Handling Exception 411');
      break;
    case ContentError.e412.name:
      print('Handling Exception 412');
      break;
    case ContentError.e413.name:
      print('Handling Exception 413');
      break;
    default:
      print('Unhandled exception');
  }
}
```

Comment: this gives me `Extension methods can't be used in constant expressions.`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the switch case and define the action each case using map and returning the method to execute correct conditions, the step explained in the code below:

```
// your input
final myString = ContentError.e410.name;

// define the action rule, like switch case
final rule = {
  ContentError.e410.name: () {
    print('do something e410');
  },
  ContentError.e411.name: () {
    print('do something e411');
  },
  ContentError.e412.name: () {
    print('do something e412');
  },
  ContentError.e413.name: () {
    print('do something e413');
  },
}[myString];

// default action, act like default 
// in the switch case
final def = () {
  print('default');
};

// execute the rule result
// if rule not contains the input
// then call default action
(rule ?? def)();
```

And this is the results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hopefully it can solve your problem, Thanks